# How do you get a list of branches that branched from a parent branch in Git?

Tags: git

We have a lot of branches (over 100) and finding the right one after months of absence is a pain. A lot are being worked on by other people, or are quite old.

I'd like to narrow the list down to only branches that have split from a known branch.

How can I get a list of branches that split from a parent branch?

Comment: I might have an idea, but do you want just the first level, or any dept. So lets say you branch B from A and C from B, do you want to list branch B and C or just B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Parent branch" is a relative term; it's user interpretation that declares which of two branch heads sharing a common ancestor is the "parent" and which is the "child". That said, you might be able to use the `--contains` option:

```
 git branch --contains <commit>
```

will list all branches whose head descends from `<commit>`. This does require you to choose a commit on your "parent" that predates the branch points for the branches you are looking for. Something like

```
git branch --contains 'master@{3 months ago}'
```

would at least give you all branches off of `master` in the last 3 months.

Comment: very good, I was thinking of `git branch --no-merged` with a combination of `git merge-base`. I'll keep your solution in mind ;)